# how to filter an array on the basis of name array?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have 2 arrays. Inside the first array I have a namelist that I want to remove from second array.

First array is simply array of strings:

```
var arrayNames = ["apple", "apricot", "cucumber"]
```

Second array is an array of custom `structs`:

```
struct fruitsData {
var name: String?
}

var secondArray = [fruitsData(name: "apple"),fruitsData(name: "apricot"), fruitsData(name: "mango"), fruitsData(name: "grapes"), fruitsData(name: "tomato"), fruitsData(name: "lichi"), fruitsData(name: "cucumber"), fruitsData(name: "brinjal")]
```

So how could I get the array which contains this data only:

```
var finalData = [fruitsData(name: "mango"), fruitsData(name: "grapes"), fruitsData(name: "tomato"), fruitsData(name: "lichi"), fruitsData(name: "brinjal")]
```

which does not include any name from `arrayNames`?

Comment: It would be nice to see your feedback about our answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

- the best way is using a `filter` method:

  ```swift
  var arrayNames = ["apple", "apricot", "cucumber"]
  var secondArray = [fruitsData(name: "apple"),fruitsData(name: "apricot"), fruitsData(name: "mango"), fruitsData(name: "grapes"), fruitsData(name: "tomato"), fruitsData(name: "lichi"), fruitsData(name: "cucumber"), fruitsData(name: "brinjal")]

  secondArray = secondArray.filter({$0.name != nil && !arrayNames.contains($0.name!)})
  ```
- alternatively, if you want to sacrifice efficiency for the sake of readability, you can use  a `for-in` loop alongside a helper Array:

  ```swift
  var arrayNames = ["apple", "apricot", "cucumber"]
  var secondArray = [fruitsData(name: "apple"),fruitsData(name: "apricot"), fruitsData(name: "mango"), fruitsData(name: "grapes"), fruitsData(name: "tomato"), fruitsData(name: "lichi"), fruitsData(name: "cucumber"), fruitsData(name: "brinjal")]
  var helperArray = [fruitsData]()

  for fruit in secondArray {

      if fruit.name != nil && !arrayNames.contains(fruit.name!){
          helperArray.append(fruit)
      }

  }

  secondArray = helperArray
  ```

The above will erase every element from `secondArray` whose name is contained by `arrayNames`. You should familiarise yourself with **[Map, Filter and Reduce](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532)**.

Answer (score 1):

Your `finalData` from `secondArray` excluding `arrayNames` can be achieved here . .

```
var finalData = secondArray.filter { !arrayNames.contains($0.name!)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on the phone so I can't check it, but this should do the trick

```
secondArray.filter { !firstArray.contains($0.name) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural approach when wanting to construct a subset array from a given array and some predicate is using `filter`. Since `name` of the `FruitsData` struct is an `Optional`, you'll need to (attempt to) unwrap it prior to comparing it to the non-`Optional` names in the `arrayNames` list, e.g. using the `map(_:)` method of `Optional` along with optional chaining for handling `nil`-valued `name` cases.

E.g.:

```
// example setup
struct FruitsData {
    var name: String?
}

let arrayNames = ["apple", "apricot", "cucumber"]

let secondArray = [
    FruitsData(name: "apple"),    FruitsData(name: "apricot"),
    FruitsData(name: "mango"),    FruitsData(name: "grapes"),
    FruitsData(name: "tomato"),   FruitsData(name: "lichi"),
    FruitsData(name: "cucumber"), FruitsData(name: "brinjal")
]

// filter 'secondArray' based on the non-existance of an
// associated fruit name in the 'arrayNames' list
let finalData = secondArray.filter {
    $0.name.map { fruitName in !arrayNames.contains(fruitName) } ?? true
}
```

Since `String` conforms to `Hashable`, you might also want to consider letting the list of fruit names to be excluded (`arrayNames`) be a `Set` rather than an `Array`, as the former will allow `O(1)` lookup when applying `contains { ... }` to it. E.g.:

```
let removeNames = Set(arrayNames)
let finalData = secondArray.filter {
    $0.name.map { fruitName in !removeNames.contains(fruitName) } ?? true
}                                        /* ^^^^^^^^- O(1) lookup */
```

---

If you'd also like to filter out `FruitsData` instances in `secondArray` that have `nil` valued `name` properties, you can simply with the `... ?? true` predicate part above to `... ?? false`: the `filter` operation will then filter out all `FruitsData` instances whose `name` property is either `nil` or present in `arrayNames`.

```
// ... filter out also FruitsData instances with 'nil' valued 'name'
let removeNames = Set(arrayNames)
let finalData = secondArray.filter {
    $0.name.map { fruitName in !removeNames.contains(fruitName) } ?? false
}
```

Comment: your solution will return all FruitsData where name == nil what is not expected.

Comment: @user3441734 I believe OP specified that only `FruitsData` instances where the `name` is also present in the non-optional `[String]` array `arrayNames` should be filtered _out_ from the `FruitsData` array. This would correspond to the expected result that `FruitsData` instances with `nil` valued `name` instances are to be kept in the filtered `FruitsData` arrays. If, on the other hand, also `nil` objects are to be removed (which has not been specified by OP), it is a simple matter of replacing the `... ?? true` with `... ?? false` in the predicate to `filter` above.

Comment: Yes, that works. Unfortunately, inverse your function is not easy, so you have to decide how to process data with nil names separately.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is NOT expected to be an empty string, you can use

```
let arrayNames = ["apple"]

struct fruitsData {
    var name: String?
}
var secondArray = [fruitsData(name: "apple"),fruitsData(name: "apricot"), fruitsData()]

// [__lldb_expr_98.fruitsData(name: Optional("apple"))]
let flt1 = secondArray.filter { arrayNames.contains($0.name ?? "") }

// [__lldb_expr_87.fruitsData(name: Optional("apricot")), __lldb_expr_87.fruitsData(name: nil)]
let flt2 = secondArray.filter { !arrayNames.contains($0.name ?? "") }
```